# Chrome extension: is it possible to initiate connection between extension and remote server from a server side?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, https, connection

**General description**

An extension need to have relevant data, so I would like a *server to notify an extension* if some data changes. All changes are made by server, so it is only between server and extension.

**What am I looking for?**

I'm looking for a way to add an *event listener* onto incoming request. In other words, I want to *access chrome extension from remote server*.

If this data may help:

- https request
- dataType - json
- script - background script
- server side language - php,  framework - any or without framework

*Thank you for your help!*

Comment: See `chrome.gcm` API. The only alternative is for an extension to poll some URL periodically or initiate a WebSocket connection and keep it open.

Comment: @wOxxom thanks, that solves my problem!